# Is there a way to change the outline color of an iOS switch in Xamarin with a renderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using this class and renderer which allows me to change the color of my switch:

```
public class ExtSwitch : Switch
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchOnColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchOnColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ExtSwitch), Color.Default);
    public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchOffColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchOffColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ExtSwitch), Color.Default);
    public static readonly BindableProperty SwitchThumbColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchThumbColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ExtSwitch), Color.Default);

    public Color SwitchOffColor { get => (Color)GetValue(SwitchOffColorProperty); set => SetValue(SwitchOffColorProperty, value); }
    public Color SwitchOnColor { get => (Color)GetValue(SwitchOnColorProperty); set => SetValue(SwitchOnColorProperty, value); }
    public Color SwitchThumbColor { get => (Color)GetValue(SwitchThumbColorProperty); set => SetValue(SwitchThumbColorProperty, value); }

}
```

and

```
class ExtSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null) return;

        ExtSwitch s = Element as ExtSwitch;

        //this.Control.ThumbTintColor = s.SwitchThumbColor.ToUIColor();
        this.Control.OnTintColor = s.SwitchOnColor.ToUIColor();
    }
}
```

This changes the color but not the outline border to the switch.  Here in this image it appears in white:

[image]

Is there a way that I could change the white border to another color in iOS?

Comment: It should just be the `TintColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the TintColor

```
this.Control.TintColor = s.SwitchOnColor.ToUIColor();
```

Comment: This does not work anymore on iOS15. It has NO border anymore :(

Comment: However, this makes the trick:  `Control.BackgroundColor = xxxxxx;`  `Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 16;` With this you have "off" tint color.